# Properties of Harmonic functions and Log

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone advise me on how to prove: If $g$ and $\text{log}|g|$ are harmonic in a simply connected domain $\Omega$, then $g \equiv$ constant on $\Omega.$

Hints will suffice, thank you very much.

Comment: Is $g$ assumed real-valued, or complex-valued?

Comment: $g$ is assumed to be real-valued.

Comment: $g$ can have no zeros (why?), so you can assume $g > 0$. Pedestrian: Compute $\Delta (\log g)$ using the Wirtinger derivatives. More elegant: mean value property and Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I am actually trying to prove: If $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and $|f|$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D},$ then $f \equiv$ constant. Hence, I thought that lemma in my main question might help.

Comment: Setting $g = \lvert f\rvert$, your question gets you the desired result. (That $\lvert f\rvert$ cannot be harmonic if $f$ has zeros is hopefully clear.)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you Sir. I have posted a question here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004206/application-of-cauchy-integral.  Appreciate if you could advise on that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\log |g| $ is harmonic then $$-\frac{1}{g^2} \left(\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)+\frac{1}{g} \left(\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}\right) =0,$$
if $g$ is harmonic then $$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}=0$$ hence $$\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)^2=0$$ but the last equality implies that $g$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, may I know why the last equality implies $g$ is constant?

Comment: If $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} =0 $ then $g(x,y) = h(y) $ but also $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} =0 $ hence $g(x,y) = v(x) $ therefore $v(x) =h(y) $ but this is possible only when $v(x) =h(y) =constant$

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something simple, but how do we know $g_x^2+g_y^2=0$ implies $g_x=g_y=0$? Couldn't we just have $g_x=ig_y$ with neither identically zero?