# Application of Cauchy Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\{|z|<R\},$ where $R>1.$

Show: $\begin{align}f(z)= i\text{Im}f(0) +\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_{0} \dfrac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}
\text{Re}f(e^{it})dt, \ \forall |z| <1 \end{align} $

My attempt: $\begin{align} \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)}\dfrac{w+z}{w-z}f(w)dw= \text{Res}(\dfrac{w+z}{w-z}f(w),z)=2zf(z) \end{align}$
$\begin{align}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C^+(0,1)}\dfrac{w+z}{w-z}\text{Re}f(w) +  \dfrac{w-z}{w+z}i\text{Im}f(w)dw \end{align}$
$\begin{align}= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\dfrac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}\text{Re}f(e^{it})dt + \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C^+(0,1)}\dfrac{w+z}{w-z}i\text{Im}f(w)dw = \ ...\end{align}$

But I can't seem to get the answer. Could anyone advise on the correct approach and point out my mistakes as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your attempt is that you have set $w = e^{it}$, but then have replaced $dt$ by $dw$ instead of $\frac{dw}{iw}$, so the integral you obtained is not easily related to

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}\operatorname{Re} f(e^{it})\,dt.$$

But even the integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)} \frac{w+z}{w-z}\frac{f(w)}{w}\,dw = 2f(z) - f(0)$$

is not so easily transformed into the desired formula.

The usual way to obtain the formula goes via the Poisson integral of harmonic functions.

Fixing $z \in \mathbb{D}$, we consider the function

$$g(w) = \frac{f(w)}{1 - \overline{z}w}$$

which is holomorphic on a neighbourhood $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, and hence by the Cauchy integral formula we have

$$g(\zeta) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)} \frac{g(w)}{w-\zeta}\,dw = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)} \frac{f(w)}{(1-\overline{z}w)(w-\zeta)}\,dw.$$

In particular, for $\zeta = z$ we obtain

\begin{align}
\frac{f(z)}{1-\lvert z\rvert^2} &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)} \frac{f(w)}{(1-\overline{z}w)(w-z)}\,dw\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)} \frac{f(w)}{(\overline{w}w-\overline{z}w)(w-z)}\,dw\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C^+(0,1)} \frac{f(w)}{(\overline{w}-\overline{z})(w-z)}\frac{dw}{w}\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f(e^{it})}{\lvert e^{it}-z\rvert^2}\,dt,
\end{align}

and from that

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}{\lvert e^{it}-z\rvert^2}f(e^{it})\,dt.\tag{1}$$

The integral representation $(1)$ is valid for all functions $f$ holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk [it is sufficient that the function is continuous on the closed unit disk and holomorphic on the open unit disk]. But the Poisson kernel

$$P(w,z) = \frac{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}{\lvert w-z\rvert^2}$$

is real-valued, hence we can take real parts and obtain the integral representation

$$h(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-\lvert z\rvert^2}{\lvert e^{it}-z\rvert^2} h(e^{it})\,dt\tag{2}$$

for all functions $h$ harmonic in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk - a real-valued harmonic function in a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk is the real part of a function holomorphic in a (possibly smaller, if the domain of $h$ has holes outside the unit disk) neighbourhood of the unit disk.

Now we note that

$$\frac{\lvert w\rvert^2-\lvert z\rvert^2}{\lvert w-z\rvert^2} = \operatorname{Re} \frac{w+z}{w-z},$$

and hence for real-valued harmonic $h$ we have

$$h(z) = \operatorname{Re} \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z} h(e^{it})\,dt\right).\tag{3}$$

But, for any continuous $g\colon \partial \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$, the function

$$z \mapsto \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}g(e^{it})\,dt$$

is holomorphic on the open unit disk. Hence

$$\tilde{f}(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}\operatorname{Re} f(e^{it})\,dt$$

is a holomorphic function on the unit disk, and by $(3)$ we have $\operatorname{Re}\tilde{f} \equiv \operatorname{Re} f$, hence $f - \tilde{f}$ is a holomorphic function attaining only purely imaginary values, therefore constant. And

$$f(0) - \tilde{f}(0) = f(0) - \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \operatorname{Re} f(e^{it})\,dt = f(0) - \operatorname{Re} f(0) = i\operatorname{Im} f(0).$$

Comment: Sir, thank you for your kind response. Could you also advise on this problem: Let $f$ be holomorphic in $\{0<|z|<1\}$ and $f$ is continuous and real on $\{|z|=1\}.$ Show $f$ can be extended to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and $f(z)= \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}, \forall z \neq 0.$ Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: It's the Schwarz reflection principle. Alternatively, you know that the extended function is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and holomorphic except possibly on the unit circle. Then you can use Morera's theorem like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1001857) to show that it is holomorphic also on the unit circle.

Comment: Sir, with regards to your solution here: $\begin{align}z \in \mathbb{D} \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_{0} \dfrac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}
f(e^{it})dt \   \end{align} $ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$, by Cauchy integral formula. But how does this imply that $\begin{align}z \in \mathbb{D} \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_{0} \dfrac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}
\text{Re}f(e^{it})dt \   \end{align} $ is also holomorphic in $\mathbb{D} \ ?$

Comment: That $f$ is holomorphic is not relevant for the integral to be holomorphic. If $K(z,t)$ is holomorphic in $z$ and continuous, for any sufficiently regular (continuous is more than enough) function $g\colon [0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$ the integral $$I(z)=\int_0^{2\pi} K(z,t)\cdot g(t)\,dt$$ is holomorphic. You get that from Morera's theorem, switching the order of integation. Here, $K(z,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}$ is easily seen to be holomorphic in $z$ and continuous. Thus $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}g(e^{it})\,dt$$ is holomorphic for every continuous $g$.

Comment: We only need the holomorphicity of $f$ to establish that $$\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\operatorname{Re} K(z,t)\,dt$$ represents $f$, and from that to deduce the integral representation $$h(z) = \int_0^{2\pi} h(e^{it})\operatorname{Re} K(z,t)\,dt$$ for harmonic $h$. Then for real-valued harmonic $h$, we see that $$g(z) = \int_0^{2\pi} h(e^{it})K(z,t)\,dt$$ is a holomorphic function with real part $h$. Then we choose $h = \operatorname{Re} f$ to deduce the desired representation of $f$.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the detailed explanation. With regards to the use of Morera theorem, one needs to show $I(z)$ is a continuous function in $z \ ?$

Comment: Yes, but that is a standard theorem in integration theory, $(z,t) \mapsto K(z,t)\cdot g(t)$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{D_r(z_0)}\times [0,2\pi]$ (for small enough $r > 0$, so that it's defined) if $g$ is continuous. For wilder $g$, use the dominated convergence theorem. To change the order of integration, you also invoke some general theorem about integrals (a more or less weak version of Fubini's theorem, depending on what regularity you assume of $g$).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have yet to learn integration theory in two variables. I believe this question here is related to proving the continuity of I(z): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006029/continuity-of-single-variable-functions-defined-in-terms-of-definite-integral/1006048#1006048

However, I think the answer posted there does not seem correct. What is your advice?

Comment: Yes, it is strongly related. It is basically the case for continuous $g$ except that here we have a complex parameter instead of a real one, but that makes no significant difference. The answer there is correct. As you comment, you have $\lvert f(x_1,y_1) - f(x_2,y_2)\rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert (x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)\rvert < \delta$. The argument for the continuity of the integral uses only the weaker $\lvert f(x_1,y) - f(x_2,y)\rvert < \epsilon$ when $\lvert x_1 - x_2\rvert <\delta$. That is the special case $y_1 = y_2 = y$ of the more general assertion you got from uniform continuity.

Comment: Fix $y_1 \in [c,d],$ given $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $\delta_1 >0$ such that $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_1)| < \epsilon,$ whenever $|x_1-x_2|<\delta_1.$ Take any $y_2 \neq y_1 \in [c,d],$ we also know there exists $\delta_2$ such that $|f(x_1,y_2)-f(x_2,y_2)| < \epsilon,$ whenever $|x_1-x_2| < \delta_2.$ So it appears to me that $\delta$ is dependent on choice of $y \in [c,d].$

Comment: so we need to consider  $\delta = \text{max}_{i \in I} \delta_i \ ?$ so when $|x_1-x_2| < \delta, |f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)|< \epsilon, \forall y \in [c,d] \ ?$

Comment: No, you don't fix $y_1\in [c,d]$. The uniform continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ means $$\bigl(\forall\epsilon >0\bigr)\bigl(\exists\delta>0\bigr)\bigl(\forall (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in [a,b]\times [c,d]\bigr) \bigl(\lvert (x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)\rvert <\delta \implies \lvert f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)\rvert <\epsilon\bigr).$$ That $\delta$ depends only on $\epsilon$, not on $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. May I know if a harmonic function defined on a disk is complex differentiable in that disk as well? I thought of this when I am trying to solve this problem here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013147/equalities-involving-integral-of-harmonic-function

Comment: In general, harmonic functions are not complex differentiable. A real-valued harmonic function is complex differentiable if and only if it is constant on each connected component of its domain. But every real-valued harmonic function on a disk (more generally, a simply connected domain) is the real part of a holomorphic function. That may help, let me take a look over there.