# Continuity of single variable functions defined in terms of definite integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ and $g(x)=f(x,y_o)$ is a continuous function defined on $[a,b],$ for each $y_o \in [c,d]. $  Could anyone advise me how to prove/disprove that $x \mapsto \int^{d}_{c}f(x,y)dy$ is continuous on $[a,b] \ ?$ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it is uniformly continuous.

Now take $\epsilon>0$. We know that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$, then $|f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)|<\epsilon/(d-c)$, for all $y\in[c,d]$.

Therefore, if $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$,
$$\left|\int_c^df(x_1,y)dy-\int_c^df(x_2,y)dy\right|\le\int_c^d|f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)|dy<\epsilon$$

I write the second paragraph with logic symbols to avoid ambiguity:

$$\forall\epsilon[\epsilon>0\implies\\\exists\delta\big((\delta>0\wedge|x_2-x_1|<\delta)\to\forall y(y\in[c,d]\to|f(x_2,y)-f(x_1,y)|<\frac\epsilon{d-c})\big)]$$

Comment: But your $\epsilon$ is dependent on each $y.$

Comment: No, and I can take this $\delta$ because $f$ is uniformñly continuous.

Comment: Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, we know that given $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $\delta  >0$ such that $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|< \epsilon,$ whenever   $|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)|< \delta.$  But this need not apply to all $y_i \in [c,d]. $