# Equalities involving integral of harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ be harmonic  on $D(0,r),$ where $r>1.$ Could anyone advise me on how to establish the following equalities:

$\begin{align} \int^{2\pi}_{0}u(e^{it})\text{cos}^2(\frac{t}{2})dt=\pi u(0)+\frac{\pi}{2}u'(0), \ \int^{2\pi}_{0}u(e^{it})\text{sin}^2(\frac{t}{2})dt=\pi u(0)-\frac{\pi}{2}u'(0)\end{align}$

My attempt:

There exists $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ such that $\text{Re}(f)=u.$

$\begin{align}\int^{2\pi}_{0} f(e^{it})\text{cos}^2(\dfrac{t}{2})dt= \dfrac{1}{i}\int_{C^+(0,1)}\frac{f(w)}{4}+\dfrac{f(w)}{2w}+\dfrac{f(w)}{4w^2}dw= 0+\pi f(0)+ \frac{\pi}{2}f^{\prime}(0) \ \end{align}$

Thank you very much.

Comment: The right hand side of the formula involves $u'(0)$, which doesn't make sense unless $u$ is complex differentiable at $0$. Can you check the assumptions again?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. $u^{\prime}(0)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(0)$

Comment: That can't be correct either. If $u$ is real-valued, then the integrals are real-valued, but $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}(0)$ generally isn't real. [Note that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ is a holomorphic function.]

Comment: Okay, I have checked with the person who set the question and it is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0).$

Comment: On other hand, may I know why $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ is a holomorphic function? Because of the Taylor expansion?

Comment: Okay, for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, all that is missing is that $f'(z) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z)$, and naturally we have $\frac{\partial (\operatorname{Re} f)}{\partial x} = \operatorname{Re} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Recall that $\Delta h = 4 \frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial\overline{z}\partial z}$. So if $h$ is harmonic [need not even be real-valued], and $g = \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}$, then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{4}\Delta h = 0$, so $g$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Noted, thank you Sir.