# If $f$ is an entire function such that $|Re(f(z))| \leq |z|^n, \forall z,$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|Re(f(z))| \leq |z|^n, \forall z$   where $n$ is a positive integer.  Could anyone advise me how to show $f$ is polynomial of degree at most $n \ ?$

Hints will suffice, thank you very much.

Comment: $u = \operatorname{Re} f$ is harmonic. Use the Poisson integral formula to find that $u$ is a polynomial (in $x$ and $y$).

Comment: Thank you Sir for your great hints. May I trouble with you another problem: Let $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be a holomorphic function such that $f(0)=0,$ $|f(z)+f(-z)|\leq 2|z|^2$ and $|f(z_o)+f(-z_o)|=2|z_o|^2,$ for some $z_o \in \mathbb{D} -\{0\}.$ Could you advise me how to prove $f(z)=e^{i\theta}z^2,$ for some $\theta\ ?$

Comment: Can you see how you obtain that $f(z) + f(-z) = 2e^{i\varphi}z^2$ for some $\varphi\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: It's the first step. We want to find out something about $f(z)$, and we have some conditions for $g(z) = f(z) + f(-z)$. If we find out what $g$ is, we know a little more about $f$ and have a shorter distance left to the goal.

Comment: Thank Sir. I will think about it

Comment: Once you know that $g$ is of the form mentioned above, you have enough information about the coefficient of $z^2$ in $f(z)$ that looking at $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(r e^{it})\rvert^2\,dt$$ finishes it.

Answer (score 2):

Better than differentiating the usual Poisson formula is using the representation of holomorphic functions

$$f(z) = i\operatorname{Im} f(0) + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{Re^{it}+z}{Re^{it}-z} \operatorname{Re} f(Re^{it})\,dt,\quad \lvert z\rvert < R\tag{1}$$

which for $R = 1$ was the subject of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004206/application-of-cauchy-integral). The generalisation to arbitrary $R > 0$ is straightforward.

This yields

$$\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f(0)\rvert + C\cdot \lvert z\rvert^n\tag{2}$$

for some constant $C$ by setting $R = 2\lvert z\rvert$ in $(1)$ for $z\neq 0$. That $(2)$ implies that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant n$ should be familiar, it is a direct consequence of the Cauchy estimates.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I have actually worked it out.

Comment: If I let $R=3|z|,$ is $\begin{align}f(z) = i\text{Im} f(0) + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{3|z|e^{it}+z}{3|z|e^{it}-z} \text{Re} f(3|z|e^{it}) \ dt \end{align}$
$\begin{align}=i\text{Im} f(0) + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2|z|e^{it}+z}{2|z|e^{it}-z} \text{Re} f(2|z|e^{it}) \ dt \end{align}, \ $ where $|z|<2|z|<3|z| \ ?$

Comment: The integral is independent of $R$, as long as $R > \lvert z\rvert$. Whether you choose $R = 2\lvert z\rvert$, $R = 3\lvert z\rvert$ or any other $R = K\cdot\lvert z\rvert$ ($K > 1$) just changes the constant you get from the straightforward estimate using $\left\lvert \frac{w+z}{w-z}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{\lvert w\rvert + \lvert z\rvert}{\lvert w\rvert - \lvert z\rvert}$ and $\lvert \operatorname{Re} f(Re^{it})\rvert \leqslant R^n$.